# An app to create an image from first page of PDF

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone recommend an app that will create an image for any given pdf.  This is for a website, the site already has thousands of pdfs stored.  I only wish to create the image of the pdf as and when I need it.

For example a webpage will check a list of ten pdf's, if no image available then create one.  So I am not interested in a tool that converts pdfs by file location, I want to be able to call it when needed to create the image.  Ideaaly i would like to have some control over quality and size of the image created.

Any help would be much appreciated?

Comment: StackOverflow is intended for programming questions, not software recommendations.

Comment: He writes "app"; from what I read, it sounds he means "lib", isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

We use [Aspose.Pdf.Kit](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/default.aspx) for this task. It's a commercial library. [This is a usage example for your specific task](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/convert-the-pdf-document-to-specified-images.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate this is a request for software recomendation, we currently use websupergoo, however not working as we wish.  Thank you Uwe. Could anyone recommend something slightly cheaper?